# A discrete distribution; domain

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_1$,$X_2$, and $X_3$ be a random sample from a discrete distribution with probability function:

\begin{cases} \frac{x}{10} & x\in \{1,2,3,4\}\\0 &\text{otherwise}  \end{cases}

what's $P(x_1<x_2<x_3)$ ?

My question is that why $x_1$ can't be $0$ or $x_3$ can't be like $5555$ or $99999$? Like $x_1=1,x_2=2,x_3=9999$

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your probability function $g(x)$ is greater than $0$ just when $x \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ so the random variable can't take any other value.

Indeed, a useful distinction in statistics is the one between the **domain** of the probability/density function and the **support**, namely the points where the function takes values greater than $0$.

Comment: if someone knows the name of the points with that property please edit my answer!

Comment: Perhaps "support" is the word you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! I'm italian and we call it 'supporto' but I thought in english was different thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can *examine* possibilities outside of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ (since your definition of $g$ allows for all numbers), but it automatically makes the probably 0, so you can optimize those possibilities out of your computations.

For example, a particular summand in $\sum_{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}} P(x1<x2<x3)P(x=x1)P(x=x2)P(x=x3)$ is just 0 when any of the three falls outside of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, so you can just skip over those cases altogether in the computation.

The distinction is between $g$ being a distribution over $\{1,2,3,4\}$ vs. over $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{N}$, etc. The context the distribution is intended for is important. For example, will all callers of $g$ know that it will only ever yield values from $\{1,2,3,4\}$, or is there a range of possible distributions of which $g$ is a special case?

(Clarification: The value of $P(x1<x2<x3)$ in my example above is deterministically either 1 or 0 based on the values plugged in. In case that was unclear.)